# How to fetch a column header if a particular condition is met based on row and column value of the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
col1    x   y   z
A      yes  no  yes
B      no   no  yes
C      no   yes no
D      yes  no  yes
E      no   no  yes
F      yes  yes no
```

I would like to select data like this, If my criteria is to find all `yes` for `A`, I should get `[x,z]`, ie the values for `A` which ever is `yes`

If `B`, `[z]`
`C` should give `[y]`

What to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create index by `col1` column for indexing by `loc`, compare by value and last get `index` values to `list`:

```
df = df.set_index('col1')

def get_val(df, idx, val):
    a = df.loc[idx].eq(val)
    return a.index[a].tolist()

print (get_val(df, 'A', 'yes'))
['x', 'z']

print (get_val(df, 'B', 'yes'))
['z']

print (get_val(df, 'C', 'yes'))
['y']
```

Comment: How to fetch out the column if a value is appering. In most cases it will give only one row.I tried this  `df =df[df.index.str.contain(val)]`

Comment: @qwww - You can use `a = df.eq(val).any()` `print (a.index[a].tolist())`

Comment: 'StringMethods' object has no attribute 'contain'` what is this error? I get it when I use str.contain

Comment: @qwww - it is typo, need `str.contains` with last `s` if want check substring

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
In [499]: df.eq('yes').dot(df.columns)[df.col1.eq('A')]
Out[499]:
0    xz
dtype: object

In [500]: df.eq('yes').dot(df.columns)[df.col1.eq('B')]
Out[500]:
1    z
dtype: object

In [501]: df.eq('yes').dot(df.columns)[df.col1.eq('C')]
Out[501]:
2    y
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another one creating a function:

```
df.set_index('col1', inplace=True)

def find_yes(df, x):
    return df.columns[df.loc[x] == 'yes'].tolist()
```

**full example**

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
col1    x   y   z
A      yes  no  yes
B      no   no  yes
C      no   yes no
D      yes  no  yes
E      no   no  yes
F      yes  yes no'''

fileobj = pd.compat.StringIO(data)
df = pd.read_csv(fileobj, sep='\s+')

df.set_index('col1', inplace=True)

def find_yes(df, x):
    return df.columns[df.loc[x] == 'yes'].tolist()

print(find_yes(df, 'A'))
print(find_yes(df, 'B'))
```

Returns:

```
['x', 'z']
['z']
```

Comment: @jezrael Ty, also noted the np.nonzero is not needed (ofc..)

Answer (score 1):

One more option for you - how about using `melt` then `groupby`:

```
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

data = StringIO('''col1    x   y   z
A      yes  no  yes
B      no   no  yes
C      no   yes no
D      yes  no  yes
E      no   no  yes
F      yes  yes no''')

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep='\s+')

m = df.melt(id_vars='col1')
matches = m[m['value'] == 'yes'].groupby('col1')\
                                .agg({'variable': list})
```

this gives the following dataframe:

```
     variable
col1         
A      [x, z]
B         [z]
C         [y]
D      [x, z]
E         [z]
F      [x, y]
```